# Undefined not a function - Drupal 7 - JQuery Dialog - No UI CSS

Tags: drupal-7, jquery-ui-dialog

I have followed tutorials such as [this one](http://andy-carter.com/blog/jquery-and-jquery-ui-in-drupal-7) and [this one](http://maxbronsema.com/blog/2013/01/18/how-to-include-jquery-ui-effects-in-drupal-7/). At first glance they are quite simple as in how to add **JQuery UI** to **Drupal 7**. Nonetheless, when I apply them, all I get is that the function **dialog** is undefined. Here is what I have done:

**template.php**

```
function mytheme_preprocess_image(&$variables) {
  drupal_add_library('system','ui.dialog');  
}
```

**chat_overlay.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("*********************Setting up click");
    jQuery('#small_chat_wrapper #chat_message').click(function(){
       console.log("*********************CLICKED CLICKED");
     if (typeof jQuery.ui !== 'undefined')
        console.log("loaded");
     else
        console.log("undefined");
     jQuery('#chat_overlay').dialog('open'); 
 });
})
```

The **console logs** print out wonderfully, and the **if check** prints out ***loaded***. Nonetheless, when it gets to the line of `.dialog(..)` the **Undefined error** occurs. I don't know what else to try. Such a simple thing and it's becoming painful.

Help is very much appreciated.

**Edit:**

The site's Status Report has the following:

*jQuery Update              jQuery 1.7.1 and jQuery UI 1.8.7*

*My MISTAKE:*

Change `function mytheme_preprocess_image(&$variables)` to `function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables)` . Goodness.

Now the **UNDEFINED ERROR** NO LONGER happens, BUT, even though the **ui classes and divs** are getting added, the UI CSS is not coming through (the dialog does not pop up).

Really would appreciate some help.

Comment: Just checking... do you have an element with the ID "chat_overlay"?

Comment: Ofcourse. As so: <div id="chat_overlay">...</div> and it has a style of "display:none;"

Comment: Are you including the full jQuery UI library?... when downloaded it lets you pick which widgets you want... is there a chance you don't have *dialog*?

Comment: Drupal 7 ships with Jquery UI by default, I never downloaded anything. "Since Drupal 7 ships with jQuery UI, the jQuery UI module has been deprecated and moved to the jQuery Update module."

Answer (score 0):

You should load the jquery library that you need either in the preprocess_html function of your template.php or in yourmodule_init hook like that:

```
<?php
  function yourmodule_init(){
    drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.dialog');
    drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.draggable');
    drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.sortable');
  }

?>
```

The source: https://www.drupal.org/node/1172846